# i have figured out some weird js minification issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

i have turned on the developer mode and did merge and minify javascript . then setup:di:compile and cache:flush the page is not looking ok but js is minifed and merged as well , when i run setup:static-content:deploy command then the main page become ok as it should look but the js minification and js merging is not working . i am stuck here i dont know what can i do in this . see if anyone facing the same issue i am using magento 2.2.6